# Как получить указатель на пиксели DC окна?

Tags: winapi, gdi, c++

Объясните пожалуйста. Есть HWND окна. Из него получаю dc: GetDC(hwnd). Теперь как мне создать контекст в памяти, совместимый с DC окна, чтобы в контексте памяти был BITMAP. И чтобы у меня был указатель на массив пикселей этого BITMAP. Не пишите, что в инете куча информации по этому поводу. Она мне мало чем помогла.

```
 HBITMAP hbmp;
 HDC windc;
 HDC memdc;
 int bits[10000];
//////////////
windc=GetDC(hwnd);
memdc=CreateCompatibleDC(windc);
hbmp=СreateBitmap(100,100,1,24,&bits);

SelectObject(memdc,hbmp);
SetPixel(memdc,1,1,RGB(255,255,0));
////////////////
WM_PAINT: BitBlt(GetDC(hwnd),0,0,100,100, memdc,0,0,SRCCOPY);`
```

Вот здесь ничего не происходит. Окно ведёт себя одиноково что с этим кодом, что без него. bits - это пиксели. По задумке, изменяя их, будет изменятся картинка в окне.

Comment: А что вы делали и что не получилось? Напишите.

Comment: @VladD, чего я только не делал... Сейчас напишу последнее, что я пробовал

Answer (score 2):

У вас не получится, доступа к байтам в памяти вам Windows не даст, потому что они не гарантируют вам формат и нужное представление. То есть вы должны нарисовать в картинку, и затем нарисовать эту картинку в DC.

Вот фрагмент рабочего кода (куски повыкидывал, надеюсь не чересчур много):

```
void Engine::OnPaint(const HDC hDC, const RECT& winClipRect)
{
    Gdiplus::Graphics graphics(hDC);
    Gdiplus::Rect clipRect(winClipRect.left,
                           winClipRect.top,
                           winClipRect.right-winClipRect.left,
                           winClipRect.bottom-winClipRect.top);

    RECT winClientRect;
    ::GetClientRect(m_hWnd, &winClientRect);
    Gdiplus::Rect clientRect(winClientRect.left,
                             winClientRect.top,
                             winClientRect.right-winClientRect.left,
                             winClientRect.bottom-winClientRect.top);

    m_MemBitmap.SetSize(clientRect.Width, clientRect.Height, &graphics);

    GraphicsContainer cont = m_MemBitmap.GetGraphics()->BeginContainer();

    // нужно чистить, у нас была транспарентность
    m_MemBitmap.GetGraphics()->Clear(0x00000000);
    m_MemBitmap.GetGraphics()->SetClip(clipRect);

    // рисуем в картинку
    pRootObject->Render(m_MemBitmap.GetGraphics(), clientRect, clipRect, false);

    // а теперь картинку на экран
    graphics.DrawImage(m_MemBitmap.GetBitmap(), 0, 0);

    m_MemBitmap.GetGraphics()->EndContainer(cont);
}
```

Здесь `m_MemBitmap` -- инстанс класса, инкапсулирующего `Gdiplus::Bitmap*` и `Gdiplus::Graphics*`, и проводящего реаллокацию, если нужно.

Comment: сейчас добавлю пример кода

Comment: @vlad, когда-то я делал это на делфи, и там как раз вот эта процедура-СreateDIBSection, последним параметром выдавала указатель

Comment: @ололо: обновил ответ